# How to scrape latitude longitude in beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am fairly new to BeautifulSoup4 and am having trouble extracting latitude and longitude values out of an html response from the below code.

```
url = 'http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1' 
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links = soup.findAll("tr")
print links
```

This code prints out this response multiple times.

```
<tr class="even location theater" data="{id: 0, point: {lng: -94.1751038, lat: 36.0848965}
```

Full tr response

```html
<tr>\n
  <th id="theater_name"><a href="/theaters/united-states?sort=name&amp;order=desc">\u2191 Name</a>
  </th>\n
  <th id="theater_location"><a href="/theaters/united-states?sort=location&amp;order=asc">Location</a>
  </th>\n
  <th id="theater_status"><a href="/theaters/united-states?sort=open&amp;order=desc">Status</a>
  </th>\n
  <th id="theater_screens"><a href="/theaters/united-states?sort=screens&amp;order=asc">Screens</a>
  </th>\n</tr>,
<tr class="even location theater" data="{id: 0, point: {lng: -94.1751038, lat: 36.0848965}, category: 'open'}">\n
  <td class="name">\n
    <a class="map-link" href="/theaters/8775">
      <img alt="112 Drive-In" height="48" src="http://photos.cinematreasures.org/production/photos/22137/1313612883/thumb.JPG?1313612883" width="48" />
    </a>\n<a class="map-link" href="/theaters/8775">112 Drive-In</a>\n
    <div class="info-box">\n
      <div class="photo" style="float: left;">
        <a href="/theaters/8775">
          <img alt="thumb" height="48" src="http://photos.cinematreasures.org/production/photos/22137/1313612883/thumb.JPG?1313612883" width="48" />
        </a>
      </div>\n
      <p style="min-width: 200px !important;">\n<strong><a href="/theaters/8775">112 Drive-In</a></strong>\n
        <br>\n 3352 Highway 112 North
        <br>Fayetteville, AR 72702
        <br>United States
        <br>479.442.4542
        <br>\n</br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
      </p>\n</div>\n</td>\n
  <td class="location">\n Fayetteville, AR, United States\n</td>\n
  <td class="status">\n Open\n</td>\n
  <td class="screens">\n 1\n</td>\n</tr>
```

How would I go about getting just the lng and lat values out of this response?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give us the URL that you're trying to scrape? Or at least the full content of the `<tr>`?

Comment: On top of what @wilbur said you'll need to use regex to grab the individual values from the table row in the example provided.

Comment: I edited the original post, regex is the only way?

Comment: No! Don't use regex. I'm writing an answer now

Comment: When attempting to use regex to parse HTML, I always refer to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @wilbur oops, I wasn't clear about what I was saying. I didn't mean to suggest using regex to parse the html. I was thinking to use BeautifulSoup to grab the data in the data tag and then use regex from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you grab all the `<tr>`s correctly, now we just need to get the data attribute from each of them.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1' 
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
theaters = soup.findAll("tr", class_="theater")
data = [ t.get('data') for t in theaters if t.get('data') ]
print data
```

Unfortunately this gives you a list of strings, not a dictionary object like one might've hoped for. We can use regular expressions on the data strings to convert them to dicts (thanks [RootTwo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5828883/roottwo)):

```
coords = []
for d in data:
    c = dict(re.findall(r'(lat|lng):\s*(-?\d{1,3}\.\d+)', d))
    coords.append(c)
```

Comment: Yea, this is nice, but a dictionary would be ideal. Thanks Wilbur.

Comment: `dict(re.findall(r'(lat|lng):\s*(-?\d{1,3}\.\d+)', data))` will return a dict.

Comment: @RootTwo _THANK YOU_! I'm not a talented enough regexer, but that's exactly right.

Comment: @sbell423 this is a much nicer way to get a list of dictionaries as a result

Comment: @RootTwo Thank you so much guys, this is exactly the result I was looking to get! Great work!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach:

```
import requests
import demjson
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://cinematreasures.org/theaters/united-states?page=1'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)

to_plain_coord = lambda d: (d['point']['lng'], d['point']['lat'])
# Grabbing theater coords if `data` attribute exists
coords = [
    to_plain_coord(demjson.decode(t.attrs['data']))
    for t in soup.select('.theater')
    if 'data' in t.attrs]

print(coords)
```

I don't use any string manipulations. Instead I load JSON from `data` attribute. Unfortunately it's not quite valid JSON here, so I'm using `demjson` library for json parsing.

```
pip install demjson
```

Comment: Nice! I hadn't heard of demjson before, I really like this solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you're expecting only a single response do:

```
print links[0]
```